# how to export only selected rows from handsontable into csv

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv, handsontable, rhandsontable

I am trying to export `csv` file from `handsontable` only for selected rows

I have tried this code using `html 5` and `angularJS`:

```
exportPlugin = hot.getPlugin('exportFile');  
$scope.exportToExcel = function(){
    if(exportPlugin!=null && exportPlugin != undefined){
        exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'file1',columnHeaders: true});
    }
}
```

I expect if I select 3 rows out of 7 rows it exports 3 rows into `csv` file

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me
first i have created array of selected rows if array has 1 or more than one record i have passed each row and column values to range property

```
function export(){
                if(exportPlugin!=null && exportPlugin != undefined){
                    var selectedRows = getSelectedRows();   
                    if(selectedRows.length > 0)
                       exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'filename',columnHeaders: true, range: [selectedRows[0], 0, selectedRows[selectedRows.length-1], htGridControl.getColHeader().length-1] });
                    else
                       exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {filename: 'filename',columnHeaders: true});
                }
              }
```